# Django allauth как получить токен юзера с которого открыта сессия в браузере?

Tags: python-3.x, django, авторизация

Доброе утро.

Нужно запостить картинку на стену vk от имени юзера который залогинился на сайте.

Пробовал получить его токен так.

```
views.py
social_accounts = SocialAccount.objects.filter(provider='vk')
for social_account in social_accounts:
    socialtokens = SocialToken.objects.filter(id=social_account.id)
```

Но мне выдает токен не того кто залогинился на сайте, а первого зарегенного через соцсеть и плюс выдает этот токен в пользование даже тем кто не авторизован.

С неавторизованными вроде разобрался. Наверно не правильно, но они уже не могут выполнить заветное действие.

```
 if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'parsing/Page1.html', {'values': ['Hello']})
    else:
        return render(request, 'parsing/Page2.html', {'values': ['не Hello']})
```

А вот получить токен юзера с которого открыта сессия не получается.
Подскажите, где можно найти решение? в документации на офф сайте такого не нашел. По форумам тоже ничего похожего не нагуглил.

Python3.6 Django2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну как мне кажется, сначала вам нужно найти нужный аккаунт для пользователя с сессии. Затем если данный аккаунт существует, искать по этому аккаунту уже его токен.

```
social_account = SocialAccount.objects.filter(provider='vk',
                                              user=request.user.pk)
socialtoken = SocialToken.objects.filter(account=social_account.pk)
```

Так должно сработать

```
social_account = SocialAccount.objects.get(provider='vk', user=request.user.pk)
social_token = SocialToken.objects.get(account=social_account)
```

Comment: Подчеркивает request, попробовал импортировать его from django.http import HttpResponse, request, но тогда пишет AttributeError: module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'user'

Comment: Добавил эти строки в основную функцию, ошибка ушла.
Теперь ошибка 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'.
Где можно найти что такое pk?

Comment: ну конечно нужно было во view добавить эти строки. И тогда для `request` ни чего не нужно будет импортировать так как это объект самого представления, `pk = primary key` попробуйте на `id` заменить.

Comment: обновил ответ, так должно заработать.